# Creating Loss Ports For Multiple Output Neural Net

Tags: neural-networks

I am making a multi-classfication neural net for a set of data. I have created the net but i think i need to specify a loss port at for each classification

Here are the labels for the classification and the encoder & decoders.

```
labels = {"Dark Colour", "Light Colour", "Mixture"}
sublabels = {"Blue", "Yellow", "Mauve"}
labeldec = NetDecoder[{"Class", labels}];
sublabdec = NetDecoder[{"Class", sublabels}];
bothdec = NetDecoder[{"Class", Flatten@{labels, sublabels}}]

enc = NetEncoder[{"Class", {"Dark Colour", "Light Colour", "Mixture", 
    "Blue", "Yellow", "Mauve"}}]
```

Here is the Net

```
SNNnet[inputno_, outputno_, dropoutrate_, nlayers_, class_: True] := 
 Module[{nhidden, linin, linout, bias},
  nhidden = Flatten[{Table[{(nlayers*100) - i},
      {i, 0, (nlayers*100), 100}]}];
  linin = Flatten[{inputno, nhidden[[;; -2]]}];
  linout = Flatten[{nhidden[[1 ;; -2]], outputno}];
  NetChain[
   Join[
    Table[
     NetChain[
      {BatchNormalizationLayer[],
       LinearLayer[linout[[i]], "Input" -> linin[[i]]],
       ElementwiseLayer["SELU"],
       DropoutLayer[dropoutrate]}],
     {i, Length[nhidden] - 1}],
    {LinearLayer[outputno],
     If[class, SoftmaxLayer[],
      Nothing]}]]]

net = NetInitialize@SNNnet[4, 6, 0.01, 8, True];
```

Here are the nodes that are used for the Netgraph function

```
nodes = Association["net" -> net, "l1" -> LinearLayer[3], 
   "sm1" -> SoftmaxLayer[], "l2" -> LinearLayer[3], 
   "sm2" -> SoftmaxLayer[],
   "myloss1" -> CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index", "Target" -> enc],
   "myloss2" -> CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index", "Target" -> enc]];
```

Here is what i want the NetGraph to do

```
connectivity = {NetPort["Data"] -> 
    "net" -> "l1" -> "sm1" -> NetPort["Label"],
   "sm1" -> NetPort["myloss1", "Input"],
   NetPort[sublabels] -> NetPort["myloss1", "Target"], 
   "myloss1" -> NetPort["Loss1"],
   "net" -> "l2" -> "sm2" -> NetPort["Sublabel"],
   "myloss2" -> NetPort["Loss2"],
   "sm2" -> NetPort["myloss2", "Input"],
   NetPort[labels] -> NetPort["myloss2", "Target"]};
```

The data will diverge at "net" for each classifcation and pass through the subsequent linear and softmax layer and to the relevant NetPort
The problem im having is at loss port which diverges at each softmax layer.

When i run this code

```
NetGraph[nodes, connectivity, "Label" -> labeldec, 
 "Sublabel" -> sublabdec]
```

I recieve the error message: NetGraph::invedgesrc: NetPort[{Blue,Yellow,Mauve}] is not a valid source for NetPort[{myloss1,Target}].

Could anyone tell me why this occurring?

Thanks for reading.

Update 10/05/2020

Thanks to @aooiiii for his help so far.

Here is the code so far

```
fakedata = <|"Data" -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}, 
   "Label" -> {"Mixture", "mauve"}, 
   "Sublabel" -> {"Light Colour", "Yellow"}|>;
labels = {"Dark Colour", "Light Colour", "Mixture"}
sublabels = {"Blue", "Yellow", "Mauve"}
labeldec = NetDecoder[{"Class", labels}];
sublabdec = NetDecoder[{"Class", sublabels}];
bothdec = NetDecoder[{"Class", Flatten@{labels, sublabels}}]
```

Heres the net

```
SNNnet[inputno_, outputno_, dropoutrate_, nlayers_, class_: True] := 
 Module[{nhidden, linin, linout, bias}, 
  nhidden = 
   Flatten[{Table[{(nlayers*100) - i}, {i, 0, (nlayers*100), 100}]}];
  linin = Flatten[{inputno, nhidden[[;; -2]]}];
  linout = Flatten[{nhidden[[1 ;; -2]], outputno}];
  NetChain[
   Join[Table[
     NetChain[{BatchNormalizationLayer[], 
       LinearLayer[linout[[i]], "Input" -> linin[[i]]], 
       ElementwiseLayer["SELU"], DropoutLayer[dropoutrate]}], {i, 
      Length[nhidden] - 1}], {LinearLayer[outputno], 
     If[class, SoftmaxLayer[], Nothing]}]]]

net = NetInitialize@SNNnet[4, 6, 0.01, 8, True];

nodes = {"net" -> net, "l1" -> LinearLayer[3], 
   "sm1" -> SoftmaxLayer[], "l2" -> LinearLayer[3], 
   "sm2" -> SoftmaxLayer[]};

connectivity = {NetPort["Data"] -> "net" -> {"l1", "l2"}, 
   "l1" -> "sm1" -> NetPort["Label"], 
   "l2" -> "sm2" -> NetPort["Sublabel"]};

netgraph = NetGraph[{
   net,
   SoftmaxLayer[]}, {NetPort["Data"] -> 1 -> 2 -> NetPort["Output"]}, 
  "Output" -> bothdec]
```

This is then passed through a total and elementwise layer to take the average of the nets:

```
ensembleNet[n_] := 
 Module[{ens}, ens = Table[NetTrain[netgraph, fakedata,
     LossFunction -> "Output", TargetDevice -> "GPU", 
     TrainingStoppingCriterion -> <|"Criterion" -> "Loss", 
       "InitialPatience" -> 50|>, 
     RandomSeeding -> RandomInteger[10^6] + n], {i, 1, n}];
  NetGraph[{Sequence @@ ens, TotalLayer[], ElementwiseLayer[#/N@n &], 
     LinearLayer[3], SoftmaxLayer[], LinearLayer[3], 
     SoftmaxLayer[]}, {NetPort["Input"] -> 
      Range[n] -> 
       n + 1 -> n + 2 -> n + 3 -> n + 4 -> NetPort["label"], 
     n + 2 -> n + 5 -> n + 6 -> NetPort["sublabel"]}, 
    "label" -> labeldec, "sublabel" -> sublabdec] // NetInitialize]
ensTrained = ensembleNet[2]
```

This does seem to work however, when observing the trained net, the loss does not decrease overtime.
[image]

[image]

Do i need to include a Loss port at sm1 and sm2 to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of `bothdec` and `netgraph`. If I'm not mistaken, a color must be one of the three `labels` and at the same time one of the three `sublabels`, but not one and only one of the six "bothlabels", so `bothdec` can be safely stripped away, and instead of training `netgraph` you should be training my `finalnet`. On Out[117], the "Output" node clearly doesn't depend on any labels (miraculously, this is what allowed illegal labels in your dataset). When used as a loss, "Output" simply returns one, because a softmax layer's output always sums to one, hence no training.

Comment: There's still no need for specifying losses (as far as I understand). After clearing out the questions and fixing the bugs, what you need is just a more elaborate NetGraph that correctly combines the ensemble networks together.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there's no need to specify the loss layers as Mathematica can attach them automatically.

```
nodes = {"net" -> net, "l1" -> LinearLayer[3], "sm1" -> SoftmaxLayer[], "l2" -> LinearLayer[3], "sm2" -> SoftmaxLayer[]};

connectivity = {
   NetPort["Data"] -> "net" -> {"l1", "l2"},
   "l1" -> "sm1" -> NetPort["Label"],
   "l2" -> "sm2" -> NetPort["Sublabel"]
   };

finalnet = NetGraph[nodes, connectivity, "Label" -> labeldec, "Sublabel" -> sublabdec];

fakedata = <|
  "Data" -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}},
  "Label" -> {"Mixture", "Light Colour"},
  "Sublabel" -> {"Mauve", "Yellow"}
  |>;

NetTrain[finalnet, fakedata]
```

Speaking of your question, the error message was generated because of a syntax error: in your code, `NetPort[sublabels]` is evaluated to `NetPort[{"Blue","Yellow","Mauve"}]`, which is obviously incorrect. If you do indeed require explicit loss specification, consult the docs for the LossFunction option. This way is a little clunkier, but I can help you with it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I may have to explicitly state the loss's. This net will branch off to another net.
I will update the question appropiately